# How to get integer from list and construct hash table in Python?

Tags: python, hash

New to python. I have a tuple variable containing some information and i convert it into list. When I print each data element out by using my for loop, I got.

```
for data in myTuple:
    print list(data)

['1', " This is the system 1 (It has been tested)."]
['2', ' Tulip Database.']
['3', ' Primary database.']
['4', " Fourth database."]
['5', " Munic database."]
['6', ' Test database.']
['7', ' Final database.']
```

The problem is how I get the the number (which is in single quote/double quotes) and store it in a dictionary as below:

```
{’1’: 'This is the system 1 (It has been tested).', ’2’: 'Tulip Database.', ...}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The keys in this case will be *strings* unless converted - maybe they should be numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by JBernardo, you could use the builtin `dict()`.

You can also use a dictionary comprehension!

```
myTuple = [['1', " This is the system 1 (It has been tested)."],
           ['2', ' Tulip Database.']]
print {key:value for key, value in myTuple}
```

Output

```
{'1': ' This is the system 1 (It has been tested).', '2': ' Tulip Database.'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dict()`:

```
my_dict = dict(myTuple)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> x = ([1, 'spam'], [2, 'foobar'])
>>> dict(x)
{1: 'spam', 2: 'foobar'}
```

`dict()` when passed an iterable does something like this(from `help(dict)`) :

```
dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
    d = {}
    for k, v in iterable:
        d[k] = v
```

Comment: why? If data is iterable, there's no need to do this